# Ajax url doesn't work if domain is entered with www at the beginning

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am not familiar at all with ajax, but I'm using a plugin at my website which uses ajax function to check if it is installed and populate it. The problem is the plugin works without problems if I enter a domain without www at the beginning like this: sevillalingerie.com (this is the website I got problems with). If I try to access it by typing www at the beginning it shows an alert error. Here's a script which I think is causing it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=module/aninews/chaeckIfModuleIsInstalled',
        //url: 'http://localhost/opencart_v1_5_4/test.php?route=ani',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            if(json['aninews_response_msg']){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=module/aninews',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#aninews").html(html);
                },
                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });

            }else{

                //alert("Module Aninew Is Creating Some Problem In Your Website");
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "tst");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: It shows an empty alert box with  text: error. To find out which error is trigerred i added a "tst" at the end of alert message. So as I see this part of error is executed:  
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText + "tst");
But that is the biggest problem: it shows nothing, and its hard to debug it.

Comment: Check ajaxOptions too. This may have some useful information.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, but if i enter ajaxOptions into alert box it just shows: error.

Comment: If i change a define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://sevillalingerie.com/');
in my config.php file to define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www. sevillalingerie.com/'); the error dissapears if webpage is accessed via www but then error appears if domain is entered without www. So as far as i see the problem must be somehow that ajax takes only one server url defined in condif.php. Any idea how to work around this ?

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to check the error. If you are using firefox or chrome, you can open it by F12 key. In the network section, you can see all requests sent during the page load and after that. Find the page you are requesting in the code and check for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after 3 hours of thinking how this could possibly be solved, I came up with this solution:
I changed my config.php define('HTTP_SERVER') function to use www with a domain. And then i altered an .htaccess file with the following code, which always adds www at the beggining of a domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```